# How to know the version of iBus I'm using?

Tags: ibus, android-studio

While downloading the components of Android Studio it was showing a message

> IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problem. See IDEA-78860 for details.

So how can I get to know which version of iBus am I using and how to update it to iBus 1.5.11?

Comment: "See IDEA-78860 for details." why did you not include the details to the question?

Comment: @Rinzwind Probably because it is hard to find. This looks like the bug report, which Google doesn't show. Perhaps some sort of robots.txt issue:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the command `ibus version` to see which version you are running. I'm still personally trying to figure out how to update it myself

edit: I found a post that breaks down installing the newest version of ibus, [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/systemd/general/ibus.html).

Also in case you run into the same error I did when attempting to install it, if you run into the error saying your intltool is too old run:

`sudo apt-get install intltool`

When you run the make command stated in the above link, you might get a lot of missing packages. For the most part just install them one by one and if need be google to find the source package for some.

Comment: Thank you, this helped when I ran into a similar issue with JetBrains Rider!

Answer (score 4):

The version of iBus or any package that you are using is normally found using `apt-cache policy package` where "package" is the name of the package that the software belongs to. In the case of iBus the package is called "ibus":

```
➜  ~ apt-cache policy ibus
ibus:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.5.11-1
  Version table:
     1.5.11-1 500
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
```

In my system, there's no iBus installed, but if I were to install it, I would get the 1.5.11 version. You can figure out which version is available for any release of Ubuntu using [madison](http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-archive/madison.cgi?package=ibus&a=&c=&s=):

```
 ibus | 1.4.1-3ubuntu1   | precise        | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
 ibus | 1.5.5-1ubuntu3   | trusty         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 ibus | 1.5.5-1ubuntu3.2 | trusty-updates | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 ibus | 1.5.9-1ubuntu3   | vivid          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 ibus | 1.5.10-1ubuntu1  | wily           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el
 ibus | 1.5.11-1ubuntu2  | xenial         | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 ibus | 1.5.11-1ubuntu3  | yakkety        | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
```

If you want a release of Ubuntu that includes 1.5.11 or later, I recommend using xenial or later.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I checked that my install of ibus was correct (the first command is to make sure ibus is present)

```
$ command -v ibus
/usr/bin/ibus

$ ibus version
IBus 1.5.14
```

Comment: The `ibus version` command was already mentioned in the accepted answer.